# Вывод из базы категорий и фотографий

Tags: база-данных, php

Привет! В Joomla есть компонент фотогалереи `DatsoGallery`. Так вот, пытаюсь вывести из базы категории фотографий из базы таким образом, чтобы выводились все категории, и к каждой выводилась одна фотография. Как это можно сделать? Там есть две таблицы, в одной все категории, в другой - фотографии.

Answer (score 1):

Выбирайте категорию и фотографию, группируя по категории, в результате будет по фотографии на категорию.

Comment: Я понял)) А как это реализовать?))

Comment: НУ помогите кто-нибудь